# How can you find which view called which partial view in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to create a debugging helper function which I can use within an MVC partial view that will show what the rendering call hierarchy is.

For example if I place

```
<%=Html.ShowRenderPath() %>
```

in my partial called endpoint.ascx and it is called from another view (midpoint.ascx) using

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("endpoint") %>
```

and this was called from another view (index.aspx)

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("midpoint") %>
```

I want the helper function to write out :

~/views/test/index.aspx -> ~/views/test/midpoint.ascx -> ~/views/test/endpoint.ascx

can anyone point me in the right direction for getting the view which rendered a partial and so on?

This is so I can debug an already existing MVC app which uses many renderpatials and it would be much easier if we could see these rendering paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply (upvote for your efforts :-)

the solution we have found instead was to update our custom view engine to output HTML comments which indicate the source of each view thereby giving a breakdown of the page construction in the source view. This was only outputted in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StackTrace` to generate a stack trace.  From that you can identify the nested view/partial view classes (amongst other stuff).  You should be able to separate out your views from the framework code through the namespaces.